# How I can do something right after one instance created with Python3?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, threadpool

I have a problem with using multiprocessing in Python3. I use multiprocessing reading multiple files and create instances with reading data. After reading and creating instances, what I want is that just right after one instances created, doing something. But it does not work as I expected.

The following code runs actually waiting for all instances created, after that do_something code are excuted. It's not what I expected.

```
import multiprocessing
import os
from itertools import repeat

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)
pool = multiproccesiin.pool.ThreadPool(processes=1)
events = list(map(lambda x: os.path.split(x)[1].split('.')[0], events))
async_results = pool.startmap_async(Writer,zip(events, repeat(self._settings['TANKDIR']), repeat(self._settings['CATDIR']),repeat(self._settings['DATADIR'])))
# Writer is my class init.
# The earliest created instance takes about 4.5 sec.
tpool.map(do_something, async_results.get())
# I thought tpool.map part start do_something right after one instance created.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tpool.map(do_something, async_results.get())` is only going to send the first `Writer` instance to the `do_something` function.

[multiprocessing.map()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map)

> This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks. The (approximate) size of these chunks can be specified by setting chunksize to a positive integer.

So, what you're doing with the `tpool.map` call is equivalent to `do_something(async_result.get())` -- ie. only sending the first `Writer` to `do_something`

Without knowing more about your use case, the solution may be as simple as `tpool.map(do_something, list(async_results))`

Comment: I tried your suggestion but failed to get what I want. I think the problem connected with 'async_reulst.get()'. get function seems to wait for all instances created. THX for you suggestion.

Comment: Ah, i believe the issue is due to the use of `starmap_async`. Any of the `*map*` functions return results in the correct order. So, even though they are executing in parallel, all must complete first before it returns any values. Hence `.get()` will wait for all to complete. You should use `apply_async` instead.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm going to try apply_async. I think it could help solving my problem. Thanks